# Focus input box when a div is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have an input inside a div element (id = "edit). I was wondering how, onclick of the div area, I could activate the cursor in the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#myDiv").click( function() {
   $("#myTextField").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `<label for="edit">` element. That would focus the `<input>` element when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
     $(this).find('input').focus()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.focus()` function like this:

```
$('#yourDiv').click(function() {
    $('#yourInput').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.attr()` to add and `removeAttr()` to remove attribute "disabled" for the text box on the event click on the div.